# SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search installation

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, installation

I have full version of SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine. Only problem is when my computer was created (by the IT Tech's at my work) they did not add the Full-Text Search feature to the installation. I would like to know if there is anywhere that you can download this feature from online. And if there is how do i install it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full-Text Search is a feature on the installation media. You will need the installation media or binaries and go through setup and add the feature to an existing installation of SQL Server. You cannot download Full-Text search as a standalone installation.

Comment: Ok thanks, so where can i download these binaries from?

Comment: Ask your IT department to install it on your PC. It will take only a few minutes of their time.

Comment: Is there no where online i can get it from. Our IT Service usually takes some time.

Comment: @GlenRobson No, you can't download the binaries unless your IT department downloaded from MSDN or volume licensing. So you may need to ask them for access.